# clone/add-new form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="input url required addnew" id="ConfigurationValues">
  <label>Bigblue</label>
  <input name="data[Configuration][value][]" value="cool" type="text">
  <input name="data[Configuration][value][]" value="awesome" type="text">
  <input name="data[Configuration][value][]" value="neat" type="text">
  <div class="actions" style="padding-left:0px;">
    <a onclick="return FALSE;" href="#" id="AddNew">Add</a>
  </div>                                        
</div>
```

I would like to replicate/clone the input. I have the below code that works for text.

```
$('a.AddNew').click(function(){
    var pool = $(this).closest('.addnew');
    pool.find('input[type=text]:first').clone().val('').insertAfter(pool.find("input[type=text]:last"));
    return false
})
```

Now i want to write generalized code the takes care of type=url,email,tel,number and select tag.

In the above code line 3-6 will change as folows

```
<input name="data[Configuration][value][]" value="neat" type="url">
```

or

```
<input name="data[Configuration][value][]" value="neat" type="tel">
```

or

```
<select></select>
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you want. What would the HTML look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
function cloneElement(selector) {
  $('a.AddNew').click(function(){
    var pool = $(this).closest('.addnew');
    var inputs = pool.find(selector);
    inputs.first().clone().val('').insertAfter(inputs.last());
    return false;
  });
}

function cloneInput(type) {
  return cloneElement('input[type=' + type + ']');
}

function cloneSelect() {
  return cloneElement('select');
}
```

EDIT: Ok, what about:

```
  $('a.AddNew').click(function(){
    var pool = $(this).closest('.addnew');
    var inputs = pool.find("input, select");
    inputs.first().clone().val('').insertAfter(inputs.last());
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: no although all elements in the div are of one type id dont know it's of which type. i am looking a generalized code